# How to effectively manage two categories of controls on a form?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-forms

On a form I have two (or more) categories of controls (currently only checkboxes):

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div class="category 1">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="cb1">Checkbox 1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="cb2">Checkbox 2</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  <div class="category 2">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="cb11">Checkbox 11</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="cb12">Checkbox 12</mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

Depending on other actions on the form, I need to control state of a category, i.e. enable/disable and check/uncheck all the controls. So I need a way to effectively iterate over a category. Currently I came up with a solution based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46259916/947012) answer, but this requires maintaining lists of names for each category.

Is there nicer/easier way to iterate over my categories?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High level - `FormGroup` type has a `controls` property which is an object of the following type `{[key: string]: AbstractControl}`, see [angular docs](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#controls).

Technically you can iterate over object properties using `for (const key in obj)` construct and manipulate your form controls.

Per [Angular docs](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#creating-nested-form-groups) you can nest `FormGroup` components to create the structure that you need to better manage the controls behavior.

Comment: Thanks, eventually I went this way, I separated controls onto different (not nested) FormGroups.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you just need to enable/disable and check/uncheck the checkbox based on conditions right?

You can do something like this in the HTML itself

The `<mat-checkbox>` has the `[disabled]` and `[checked]` attribute in its API. You can make use of it.

You can use `*ngIf` to control the conditions.

It will turn out something like this:

```
 <form [formGroup]="someForm">  // Don't name your form as 'form'. Not a good practice
  <div class="category 1">
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="cb1">Checkbox 1</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox formControlName="cb2">Checkbox 2</mat-checkbox>
  </div>

// Enable the second category only if both the above checkboxes are having a value
  <div class="category 2" *ngIf="someForm.controls.cb1.value && someForm.controls.cb2.value"> 
    <mat-checkbox 
        formControlName="cb11"
        [disabled]="!someForm.controls.cb1.value"  // This will be disabled if the value is false which will make the condition true
    >
       Checkbox 11
    </mat-checkbox>


    <mat-checkbox 
       formControlName="cb12"
       [checked]="someForm.controls.cb1.value" // It will be checked only if cb1 is checked
    >
       Checkbox 12
    </mat-checkbox>
  </div>
  ...
</form>
```

You need not do it from the TS always. But if you want to do that in the TS, you will write something very similar:

```
this.someForm.controls.cb1.valueChanges.subscribe(data => {
   if (data) {
     this.someForm.controls.cb2.disable();

     // After this you can remove the validators for the disabled field
     this.someForm.controls.cb2.setValidators(null);
     this.someForm.controls.cb2.updateValueAndValidity();
   }
})
```